# Spotify Google Analytics API

Tags: spotify, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics API.
But, there is no way to get the Data on google analytics.
Do I forget something ?

```
var gtrack = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/googletracker");
var tracker = new gtrack.GoogleTracker('UA–xxxxxxx–1');
tracker.track('APPNAME/modulename');
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 2):

Three things come to mind:

- I am assuming in your code you've replaced 'UA–xxxxxxx–1' with your actual property ID from Google Analytics. This is probably obvious, but it can't hurt to ask. :)
- Double check you've added the correct permissions to your manifest, as explained here: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#usertrackinganalytics. Changes to the manifest only take effect after you restart your Spotify client.
- Even once you've configured everything correctly, it can take several hours (even days if you have a lot of traffic) for data to become available on the traditional Google Analytics dashboards. I highly recommend using [the real-time dashboard](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html) for debugging.

Comment: Ok, then, I double check :
- UA is correct
- RequiredPermissions is an array and is correctly filled with Google Analytics.